# Understanding the picture of monoidal space

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, semigroups-and-monoids, log-geometry

Ogus in his slides [https://math.berkeley.edu/~ogus/preprints/colloqhandout.pdf](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Eogus/preprints/colloqhandout.pdf) presents the following picture of a monoidal space $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{N} \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}[\mathbb{N}])$:
[image]

Picture of $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{N})$ is clear, the generic point corresponds to the empty ideal. But what is the precise meaning of the bottom picture? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not [write to him](https://math.berkeley.edu/people/faculty/arthur-e-ogus) and ask?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ogus states that he draws a log scheme $(X,\mathcal{M})$ by first drawing $X$ and then adding a picture of $\operatorname{Spec}\mathcal{M}_x$ at each $x\in X.$ (He says this on page 21.)

In this case, $\operatorname{Spec}\Bbb{C}[\Bbb{N}] \simeq \operatorname{Spec}\Bbb{C}[t],$ so the pictured disk is the complex affine line, represented as a subset of the complex plane. We can also compute $\mathcal{M}_x$ for each $x\in\operatorname{Spec}\Bbb{C}[\Bbb{N}].$ At the points other than the origin, the log structure on $\operatorname{Spec}\Bbb{C}[\Bbb{N}]$ is trivial in the sense that $\mathcal{M}_x \simeq\mathcal{O}_{X,x}^\times.$ However, at the origin, we have $\mathcal{M}_x\simeq \mathcal{O}_{X,x}^\times\times\Bbb{N},$ and the origin gets embellished with a picture of $\operatorname{Spec}\Bbb{N}.$

It seems to me that the picture really decorates each point $x\in X$ with a picture of $\operatorname{Spec}(\overline{\mathcal{M}}_x),$ where $\overline{\mathcal{M}} = \mathcal{M}/\mathcal{O}_X^\times$ is the *characteristic* of the log structure.